# Can I test the construction of a LINQ query without actually executing it

Tags: .net, unit-testing, linq-to-entities, tdd

I have heard that when testing EF, you need to use integration testing against a live DB because of the differences between the LINQ to Objects and LINQ to Entities providers.

Why can't we unit test the *construction* of the query without actually *executing* it?  I would have thought you could just attach your IQueryable to the LINQ to Entities provider *somehow* and confirm the SQL is generated properly (using something like ToTraceString which does not execute the actual query).

I imagine code along these lines (this query would run fine in L2O but not in L2E):

```
    <Test()> _
    Public Sub Query_Should_Build_Against_L2E()
        Dim testQuery = From d In myDb
                        Where d.Status = CType(Status.Ready, Integer)

        testQuery.SetQueryProvider("L2E")

        Assert.DoesNotThrow(testQuery.ToTraceString())
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I tried implement GertArnold's solution as follows:

```
Dim context As New Context("Data Source=fakedbserver;Initial Catalog=fakedb;Persist Security Info=True;")
Dim result = context.myTable.Where(Function(d) d.Status=True)
```

That throws a `ProviderIncompatibleException` with the message "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."  Here's the full exception chain:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException : An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
>
> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException : The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException : This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Note it isn't as simple as "L2E"; the engine is free to have different SQL dialects for different versions of a single DB (i.e. "SQL Server 2008 r2" vs "SQL Server 2008" vs "SQL Server 2005" vs "SQL Server 2000"), and EF supports more than just SQL Server. Frankly, to me it makes a lot more sense to run it as an integration test.

Comment: @MarcGravell There's no overall provider which handles creating a "convertible" expression tree?  I assume that all the L2E providers will fail on the CType example I gave in the question above.  Are there actual differences in what subset of expressions the different L2E providers support?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even look at the specific query; `CType` may or may not be supported *at all* (I honestly don't know), but I was thinking more generally; i.e. assume an expression *can work* - that doesn't mean it *will work* on every possible back-end.

Comment: I personally find because of delayed execution, these "invalid expression" errors can buried very deeply inside a query and be hard to ferret out (and they manifest with many different exceptions depending on the specific case).  If I saw an fail appear in my unit tests the minute I added the invalid L2E statement, it would make spotting and repairing the problem *much* quicker.  So, I can have integration tests as well on this for total verifiability, but if possible I would like the unit tests.

Comment: fair enough; it will be interesting to know if it is possible...

Answer (score 2):

> attach your IQueryable to the LINQ to Entities provider

The question is: which `IQueryable`? An interface in itself is nothing. Working with EF, you're dealing with classes that implement `IQueryable` but besides that do a lot more. In fact, they are fully equipped to cooperate with the context and the query provider that *already is attached* below the hood. `IQueryable.IQueryProvider` is a read-only property, so it is set by the factory that creates the specific `IQueryable` implementation.

Thus, your `testQuery` would be an `ObjectQuery` because it is taken from `myDb` which could not be anything else than an EF context.

> Why can't we unit test the *construction* of the query without actually *executing* it?

Isn't this your actual question? In fact, I even wonder if you would want a different query provider for that. I think you would want the EF query provider that act like this, otherwise there still is no guarantee that with EF it works the same.

Anyway, you can create a context with a phony database name in it's connection string (to make sure it does not connect) and check the validity of `((ObjectQuery)testQuery).ToTraceString()`. It's OK as long as you don't iterate over `testQuery`. I can imagine that there is some value in such a test when queries are composed in complex execution paths. (But I'd prefer to avoid that).

Comment: Do you work code-first or database-first? I did this with an ObjectContext.

Comment: The project I'm working on atm is code-first.  (I mentioned ToTraceString because I have done work with db first/model first in other projects)

Comment: What if you use a DbContext with an empty connection string? BTW you can use `testQuery.ToString()` (it's a `DbQuery`). Are you sure the query is not actually running?

Comment: I am using ToString, thanks =D.  I just tried an empty connection string, it shows me the same exception trace without the first ProviderIncompatibleException.  The line which runs the query is throwing the exception...

Comment: I can do it with a code-first context against an existing database (not created by EF), when I try the same with code-first and a database created by EF I get your exception. Propably because an effort is made to get the metadata from the database. Looks like you'd still need a valid connection string, which more or less defeats the purpose of your unit test :(

Answer (score 0):

#### The short answer

I was able to create a mock DbContext which "connects" to the right EF provider *without any actual db connections*.  This guarantees the LINQ under test will actually work in a integration scenario against your real database.  It's currently only implemented for MS SQL Server, but it should be very easy to expand to other EF providers.  I've posted the full code below, I'd be very happy to hear feedback on it.

*EDIT* I moved the code to a [GPL CodePlex project](http://fakedbconnection.codeplex.com/).

#### The long answer

After looking at [GertArnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gertarnold)'s answer and rethinking the entire problem (and extensive reflection on the sources), I came up with what I think is a viable solution.  The problem is that the default configuration for a DbContext is to:

1. Use the default `SqlConnectionFactory` to create a connection to the database requested by the `nameOrConnectionString` property of the `DbContext` constructor
2. Create the database if it does not exist (because it uses `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` as the default context initializer)
3. Open a connection to the database to confirm it is accessible (using `DbConnection.Open` and `DbConnection.State`)
4. Query the database to confirm the requested model exists in it (using `System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModel` which in turn creates a command on the active connection to query the db for the model)
5. Build a `System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices` and a `System.Data.Common.DbProviderManifest` object which together provide support for **translating Expressions into SQL**.

The first four of those steps (which require actual db connectivity) can be creating a new `IDatabaseInitializer` which does nothing in the `InitializeDatabase` method, then registering for the context type under test with `Database.SetInitializer`.

Step 5, on the other hand, is the reason the we need a real DbContext for selection at all.  Without the DbProviderServices and DbProviderManifest, EF would have no idea how to translate the expressions.  I was able to use reflection to get the internal `SqlProviderManifest` and `SqlProviderServices` and pass the work off to them (I can even specify which SQL server version to use by year).